# name 'privtopub' is not defined

Tags: python, bitcoin, private-key, public-key

My code looks like:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Details
from bitcoin import *
import random
import bs4
import requests

def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.htm')

def register(request):

    detail = Details()
    bits = random.getrandbits(256)
    bits_hex = hex(bits)
    private_key = bits_hex[2:]
    print(private_key)
    # private_key = random_key()
    public_key = privtopub(private_key)
    address = pubtoaddr(public_key)
    detail.private_key = private_key
    detail.public_key = public_key
    detail.address = address
```

But I get the error: `name 'privtopub' is not defined`

Comment: Hi there  Please do not open [the same question on multiple stackexchange sites](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116446/nameerror-at-register-name-privtopub-is-not-defined). There is not a `privtopub` function in the code listing, perhaps there's a library that was not imported?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by importing bitcoin as:

```
import bitcoin
```

rather than

```
from bitcoin import *
```

The latter is not ideal programming practice and is said to "clutter the name space."

Then change your:

```
public_key = privtopub(private_key)
```

to:

```
public_key = bitcoin.privtopub(private_key)
```

and see if your problem goes away.

Also, it looks like `privtopub()` may be an alias for `privkey_to_pubkey()` . So maybe your version of `bitcoin` is older and doesn't have the alias. If so, you can also try just calling the method by the longer name.